# Transitive Property of Proper Inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> *$ Theorem:$
>     If $  A \subset B $ and  $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C$.*

Here $X \subset Y$ is defined as $ X\subseteq Y$ and $X\neq Y$.

I can prove the case of improper inclusion using the transitive property of implication to show that $ A\subseteq C$ but can't seem to figure out the $A \neq C$ part of the definition.

Inclusion $X \subseteq Y$ is defined to mean: $x \in X \implies x \in Y$

Can please provide a proof or suggestion. Obviously inequalities are not transitive right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, inequality is not transitive since $1\neq 0 \neq 1$ does not imply $1\neq 1$.

To show that $A\neq C$ you can proceed as follows: Given that $A\subsetneq B$, there exists some $b\in B$ such that $b\notin A$. Since $b\in B$ and $B\subsetneq C$, we have $b\in C$. Now $b\notin A$ and $b\in C$, thus $A\neq C$.

As noted by BrianO, the following is perhaps more straight forward: Choose $c\in C\setminus B$, which means $c\notin B$ and thus $c\notin A$. Hence $A\neq C$.

Comment: You don't have to assume $B$ nonempty, it's implied by $A\subsetneqq B$. A simpler proof: let $c\in (C\setminus B)$; then $c\notin B$, so $c\notin A$.

Comment: Good point, thanks!